# How to get boolean result back from windows command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, msbuild

I have following commands in a `.bat` file that is being called from another `.vbs` file. My requirement is to stop executing the following line and notify user by writing something back to command prompt or pop up(pop up preferred) if `msbuild/t:clean` doesn't complete execution without any issue. I would like to add a `if` condition after and execute `msbuild/p:configuration=%1`. After successfully completion I would also like to notify user the whole process was successful or failed through command prompt or pop up alert. Can these be done?

```
call "%VS130COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
cd c:\working\develop

msbuild/t:clean
msbuild/p:configuration=%1
```

Comment: does `msbuild`provide an errorlevel? (put `echo %errorlevel%` into  the following line and try) Most programs return `0` if successful or "non-zero" for any failure.

Comment: @Stephan, I wondered the same about error codes. Couple hours of research shows a range of failure error codes, but wide consensus (especially at MSDN) that successful completion returns errorlevel 0.

Comment: @sjoy, yes, every developer is free to choose whatever errorlevels (exitcodes) they want (or to use an exitcode at all). Only consense is "0" for success, but once I've even seen an errorlevel "1" to mean "successful"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following batch file should do what you need. It checks for successful completion after each msbuild job and if job failed, indicated by errorlevel >0, notifies the user (in CMD window) and exits. When both jobs finish, it tells the user so.

You say, "I have following commands in a bat file" so I assume this is the bat called from the vbs file and it includes the call to vsvars32.bat. If this *is* vsvars32.bat, obviously you need to delete the call and put remaining code into that bat.

```
@echo off
    cls
    echo. &echo
        call "%VS130COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
        cd c:\working\develop
        ::  Job 1
            set errorlevel=0
            msbuild/t:clean
                If %errorlevel% NEQ 0 set "job=msbuild/t:clean" &goto err
        ::  Job2
            set errorlevel=0
            msbuild/p:configuration=%1
                If %errorlevel% NEQ 0 set "job=msbuild/p:configuration=%1" &goto err
        ::  Success
            echo msbuild jobs completed successfully
            echo Will exit when you press any key. &pause >nul &exit
:err
        echo ERROR: %job% failed to complete
        echo Will exit when you press any key. &pause >nul
exit
```

Comment: Setting `"errorlevel=0"` always returns error level to `0` and says build is always successful. However, I removed that and getting error level from msbuild which is `0` for failure and getting expected result in my case. Thanks!

Comment: @Saifur Hmm...just want to be sure this code is right for others too. If 0 is fail for these jobs, then the line `If %errorlevel% NEQ 0` would not work--the `NEQ 0` (not equal 0) would be detecting success. If it works, then your errorlevel must be 0. Did you also change `NEQ 0` to `EQU 0`? If yes, I will fix the code here. thx

Comment: @Saifur I think prob with `set` was quote marks around `errorlevel=0`. I removed them in answer.

Comment: I didn't change that to EQU. I assume my errorlevel is0

Comment: @Saifur (lol for all the comments) By changes I think you mean removing quotes. Unless you comment back I assume this code is all good now

Answer (score 1):

`msbuild` returns a zero exit code on successful completion, and a non-zero exit code in case of an error, so something like this should do:

```
call "%VS130COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
cd c:\working\develop

msbuild /t:clean
set "rc=%errorlevel%"
if %rc% neq 0 goto END
msbuild /p:configuration=%1
set "rc=%errorlevel%"

:END
exit /b %rc%
```

or (using delayed expansion) something like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call "%VS130COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
cd c:\working\develop

msbuild /t:clean
set "rc=%errorlevel%"
if %rc% equ 0 (
  msbuild /p:configuration=%1
  set "rc=!errorlevel!"
)

exit /b %rc%
```